# Datanitro insert Images

Tags: python, excel, datanitro

How do I control the position and size of an image on the Excel sheet using Datanitro?

I want to insert and resize an image and change the position by setting the active cell.

First, I need to insert several images and I change the position using `picture.y` and `lock_images()`. Then I can't put them in equal rows distance, for example `cell(A1)`, `cell(A11)`, `Cell(A21)`...

Secondly when I try, for example `picture.width = 400` to resize the images, datanitro gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: Can't set attribute.
```